# Why is the output of this C code 1?

Tags: c

Why is the output always 1 no matter what string i enter.
Please explain

```
int  main() {
    char ch[]={};
    printf("%d", scanf("%s", ch));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior aside, the output of this program depends a great deal on what you input. If you press Ctrl+D (Ctrl-Z on windows) your program will print zero.

Comment: You could have easily solved this yourself by reading any of the available online references for `scanf`.

Comment: You are "lucky " it works considering `ch`  has no size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man page of [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> **These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned**, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
>   the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is
>   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
>   indicate the error.

So, It means `scanf()` returns number of items successfully read.

Also, C not allowed zero size arrays.

**C11 6.7.6.2 Array declarators :**

**Paragraph 1:**

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [
>   and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression
>   (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an
>   integer type. **If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an
>   incomplete or function type.** The optional type qualifiers and the
>   keyword static shall appear only in a declaration of a function
>   parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array
>   type derivation.

Comment: This answer is wrong, `char ch[]={};` is invalid in both C & C++. Zero size arrays are not allowed. See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1da9f5b8d1491d45)

Comment: @Destructor Hellos sir, i added paragraph about zero size array. Thanks for suggested me.

Answer (score 3):

Because `scanf` returns the number of items it reads. In your case, it is reading one string and thus it returns 1 which is then printed to the standard output through `printf`.

Comment: @anonymoose Yes, to be precise.